# When does OS flush the socket?

Tags: sockets

Suppose I have this Python code:

```
read=true;
i=0;
while (read){
    data =sock.recv(100);
    i+=1;
    print data;
}
```

Now on the other end I feed the socket with 101 character. At the end of receiving the value of `i` will be 2, because all the feed will not end up in a buffer of 100 chars - one remaining char will go to another iteration. That's understandable: buffer fills-up, information is flushed to a variable `data`.
But what happens if I feed the socket with 10 chars only? Buffer does not fill-up, so how on Earth does this `sock` know that after 10 chars are received there will be no more stream coming and it's time to flush the buffer and return the message to 'data'?

Actual copy-paste example:

SERVER:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind("/tmp/somesfile")
s.accept(1)
s.listen()
conn, addr = s.accept()

i=0
read=True

while read:
    conn.recv(10)
    i = i + 1
    print i
```

CLIENT:

```
c = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c.connect("/tmp/somesfile")
```

SENDING DATA (console on CLIENT)

```
>>> c.send("aaaaa")
5
>>> c.send("a")
1
>>> c.send("a")
1
>>> c.send("a")
1
>>> c.send("a")
1
>>>
```

RECEIVING DATA (console on SERVER)

```
'aaaaa'
1
'a'
2
'a'
3
'a'
4
'a'
5
```

Server has 10-byte buffer prepared for received data. On a first burst it received 5 chars - all 5 were stored to the same buffer and flushed. On further 4 bursts server was send 4 shars one-by-one with time interval between receives. All these chars were flushed in the same pattern, i.e. one-by-one.  In none of the cases buffer whas filled. My question is: what causes server socket to flush the buffer apart from overfill? How does it now that another byte will not come?

Strings are null-terminated patterns of bytes. Are socket streams something-terminated?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The way `recv` works, you get whatever is in the buffer, up to the amount that you ask for (this means: possibly less than what you ask for). So if there are only 10 bytes, you get 10 bytes. What's the special issue that the OS has to deal with?

Comment: and if you ask for 10 bytes and there are only 5? will it block the process flow until someone feeds it with 5 more bytes and fill the buffer? I might be spoiled by python.. everything is oversimplified there....

Comment: I do not recall how it is in C, but in Python if I recv(100) and feed the socket to the other end with 100 bytes one-by-one (say with 1 second delay between feeds) the process will unblock 100 times. If I feed it with 100 bytes at once - recv() will unblock only once. Which means that recv() releases the block even when the buffer is not full.  Basically I send the same data just in different portions, and the process behaviour is different

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python or C,  but with the underlying sockets API. As long as there is at least 1 byte in the receive buffer, `recv` will return this instead of blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the end of receiving the value of i will be 2

No. It could be anything from 2 to 101. `recv` reads at least one byte and at most as much as has been sent by the remote side. It can read any amount in between.

> so how on Earth does this sock know that after 10 chars are received there will be no more stream coming

It doesn't. It gives you what's there.

Comment: I have modded my question with an example of what's bugigng me.. How come it can be anything [2;101]? Why >2 if I send data with the same stream? I know recv() reads at least one byte, but how comes it does not return bytes one-by-one and is intelligent enough to know when stream has ended and return whatever is in a buffer although it's not full? What's the trigger?

Comment: Again, it does not know when the stream has ended. It gives you data as it comes in. TCP has no messages. The chunk size that you use to send data has no guaranteed effect on the chunk size that is received. In practice certain behavior are very common but that is nothing to be relied upon.

Comment: Try this by executing `c.send("a")` two times in a row faster than 200ms apart. You'll likely receive "aa" in one recv call. That's nagling at play.

Comment: So... is it time-dependant? Say if I recv(2048) and then send 2048 bytes as a single message through the network where MTU=1500. recv() received 1500 bytes and then suddenly there was a glitch in network after which remaining bytes have been sent. Will the server receive all the message as 2 distinct messages due to the time difference between network packets?

Comment: You're not getting what I'm saying. There is no way you can ensure that the data stream is received in certain chunks. Do you understand that? Are you asking out of curiosity what happens in practice most of the time?

Comment: I have understood this the first ime you said. However It's still not clear to me what causes recv() to flush.. Is it like while(1) {data=data_in_queue(); if(data->size > 0) { read_data_that_has_reached_server; } else {break;} } ? It would mean that it's dependent entirely on time, i.e. whether kernel buffer is filled faster than one while() loop iterates one time. If loop iterated faster - recv() buffer content is flushed, elsewise data chunk from kernel buffer is added to recv() buffer and while() iterates again.. I'm just trying to understand how this mechanism works and what it depends on.

Comment: The sender just sends out network packets immediately. The moment they arrive at the receiver the recv call returns that data. If nagling is enabled the sender batches data for 200ms or until one packet is full. At least that's how it works approximately. None of this is important to know for correctness because you can't rely on it.; The sender cannot know if and when data is received. It just sends.

Comment: Okay, diving into glibc and kernel sources again.... :) I like to know things a bit more in detail.. for now it's not clear for me where freshly received data is stored and how recv take it.. I'd assume that there are several buffers: kernel and recv(). Kernel stores received data until it's demanded by recv() OR socket is closed - whichever happens first. recv() could be pumping data from kernel bufer to its own with while(1) loop and once kernels buffer (queue) is empty - recv() breaks from loop and returns it's bufer contents... This is my assumption only on a short preview of several srcs.

Comment: That would also explain why you can send() without recv() called. If that's the case - recv() returns once kernel has no more info to supply to it. That would mean that recv() is time- and recv()-buffer_fill-dependant and these would be the only triggers for returning from the syscall... Actually I'm now waiting for @usr to call me a fool as these are only my speculations without actually knowing for sure :)

Comment: I wouldn't call recv time dependent. It simply returns you the data that is available right now or waits until something becomes available (which usually is one network packet). recv does not contain a loop. The app must loop. It really is quite simple what it does. The kernel does buffer some data, yes. See the TCP spec to see how throttling works. You can safely send 1TB of data and have no recv call and the connection will survive that without problems.

Comment: int rds_recvmsg contains a loop... although not completely sure what rds means.. (datagram sockets, yes, but are all the sockets built on top of them? maybe I'm barking at a wrong tree..?) while(1){ <...> if(! rds_next_incoming(rs, &inc)) {<...>} } ...

Comment: I think I understand it now.... " (which usually is one network packet) "   was the icebraker :) Thank you /usr.